# how can I implement my own prolog structure for a hashmap

Tags: hashmap, prolog

I am new to Prolog language, and i would like to implement my own structure for a hashmap. I wish to do a type analyser for a certain grammar (so i would like to create an environment structure to store (variable,value), and then implement some "methods" to access, extract,print...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use many facts, e.g. `my_map(variable1,value1).`, `my_map(variable2,value2).`, etc. ? Access `my_map(variable1,X).` Print `my_map(vairable1,X),write(X).` and so on.

Comment: I'm really new for Prolog, so I didn't really know how to do it. But now it's clear, thank you

Comment: FYI I use the same thing for test cases and have almost 800,000 in one file.

Comment: @venilla you ask new question in comments, this is not good, maybe better to ask new question in new question, not in comments to old question which has answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

Why not just use many facts, e.g. `my_map(variable1,value1).`, `my_map(variable2,value2).`, etc. ? Access `my_map(variable1,X).` Print `my_map(variable1,X),write(X).` and so on.